# Laravel redirect()->with('status','My message') error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a email verification on Laravel 5.2. When a user fill the registration form and is validated they return the user to login form with:

```
return redirect('/login')->with('status','We send a email verification, please
confirm.');
```

And this works perfect. The problem is when the user click on link verification in his inbox they activated the account and redirect to admin page but without status message. Here is the code for that in AuthController.php:

```
public function activateUser(Request $request,$token)
{
    if ($user = $this->activationService->activateUser($token)) {
       return redirect('/login')->with('status','You account is now activated. Please login.');
    }
    abort(404);
}
```

On my login.blade.php:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Please, someone know why the session variable is not working?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code where you want to show the message?

Comment: try changing if ($user = $this->activationService->activateUser($token)) to if ($user == $this->activationService->activateUser($token)). You have single = sign in your if statement.

Comment: @RuhulAmin I edited check my code again. Thanks.

Comment: @boroboris I change that and say's $user variable it's not defined.

Answer (score 1):

it should work like this. in your `AuthController`, just change

```
  return \Redirect::to('/login')->with('status','You account is now activated. Please login.');
```

and in your `login.blade`

```
 @if (Session::has('status'))
       <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <p>{{ Session::get('status') }}</p>
       </div>
 @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey i don't what happend here and why redirect()->with() is not working. I solved doing a new view called activated.blade a copy of login.blade but with a message saying: "You account is now activated. Please login." so i do this in the controller:

> return redirect('/activated');